# Closing response stream

Tags: go

Should we do this:

```
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()
```

or this:

```
response, err := http.Get(url)
defer response.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I guess response can be nil. But I wonder if response can be created, but still get an error?
I guess I would do something like this?

```
response, err := http.Get(url)
if response != nil {
   defer response.Body.Close()
}
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Use the pattern shown right at the very top of the documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#pkg-overview

Comment: The second option will be liable to panic any time you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code block is correct

From the documentation

> The client must close the response body when finished with it:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

If there is an error the response is nil